# PHPExcel : Set header string in the first page only

Tags: phpexcel

The following line insert the string in the header of each printed page:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHeaderFooter()->setOddHeader('abcd');
```

When I try with this one, nothing is insert at all:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHeaderFooter()->setFirstHeader('abcd');
```

What is the best way to insert a string in the header of the first page only?

Thanks.